# Geckofx get specific links from a page

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

```
var links = new List<GeckoElement>();
foreach (var link in geckoWebBrowser1.Document.Links)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(link.GetAttribute("href").ToString()))
        links.Add(link);
    }
}
```

I have this code to collect all links in the page, but I cant figure it out how can I filter to some specific links that starts with for example "ow.ly". Rest in the list should be ignored.

Tryed this but didnt seem to work

```
if (links.Count > 0)
{
    if (links.Equals("ow.ly"))
    {

    }
}
```

When I debug if links equals ow.ly it shows 0 reults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`links` is a a `List<GeckoElement>`. So it’s unlikely that the list equals to the string `"ow.ly"`. Instead, you want to filter the list for items, which `href` property contains that text.

You could do that for example like this:

```
var owlyLinks = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.Links.Where(link =>
{
    string hrefAttribute = link.GetAttribute("href").ToString();
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(hrefAttribute) && hrefAttribute.Contains("ow.ly");
}).ToList();
```

You might want to adjust the check so that `"ow.ly"` needs to appear somewhere special instead of just somewhere inside the string. For example, you could parse the whole Url, and then check that the host name equals to `ow.ly`.